# after updating at apple store some buttons are not visible in my app

Tags: ios, iphone, button, ios8

my app was updated today. (https://itunes.apple.com/tr/app/itu-kampus/id906666198?mt=8) but some  buttons in the app are not visible. I tried app on all device simulator and my device iPhone 4S, my app was working wery vell before sending apple store. How to fix this problem ?

Thanks in replies

Before - After
http://imgim.com/8803inciu4396627.png

Comment: I think the button images are taken the reference not copied to Xcode project. Check once the Final ipa file in Device.

Comment: you have to test adhoc distribution build before submitting.In simulator derived data can cause images to show clear derived data and run your images will not be there. Add images make ipa and re submitt

Comment: Can you able to tap on area where this images are suppose to be. I mean are you able to get the action of that buttons?

Comment: Thanks for your comments Suresh Thoutham and amar; my app was working very well before. for update ios8 i didn't change any image folder.  and as i said before this version of app was working when debugging from xcode.

Comment: @Kampai I'm not able to get action of this buttons :S

Comment: @amar Is there any differences between debugging from xcode and testing my app at adhoc distribution ?

Comment: yes the derived data is the diffrence. If you see your buttons while debugging from xcode kindly clear your derived data clean your project then try again chances are you will not see your images...but since you are not able to tap on button there could be some other issues as well..delete the previous install before testing again

Comment: @amar  apple has changed  xcode auto layout systems. I used constraints for arrange the buttons locations. Is this problem caused this situation ?

Comment: very possible reason many cases of things not working on iOS8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researching I solved the problem. It caused by storyboard's layers differences. Button layer and map layer changed. After moving button layer up to mape problem was solved.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that when you add your images to your project you select the "Copy if needed" checkbox in the popup. Otherwise you can use the asset.catalog to ensure that image resources are copied to your project folder.

Comment: Thanks your reply. 
My other pictures inside same folder but they are visible, only some button images are not visible.

Comment: They are visible because they are available in your mac but that they are not packed with the archive if you do not choose to copy them in destination folder. Remove them and add them again with the copy checkbox selected.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably an image scaling issue. ensure you have the right dimension (@2x etc.)